# iPhone: copy–paste of URL not working

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, copy-paste, twitter

I sometimes want to tweet a link from my iPhone (4s / iOS 8). On iOS 6 I used to simply copy the URL from Safari and paste it into the text field of the twitter app.

- Placing the 'cursor' inside URL field inside Safari's URL field
- choosing 'select all' from context menu
- clicking on 'copy' in context menu
- switching apps –> twitter
- choosing 'paste' from context menu

This however seems to not work anymore on iOS 8. Workflow for sending an email with an URL was the same – and also does not work anymore.

Everytime I try to copy a URL as I used to, anything I copied ***before*** that url is pasted instead.

I do have a work around now: clicking the 'share by email' icon will open a new email with that link already in the text field which I then can copy to twitter. But I'm just wondering if anybody else has found a way how to copy URLs into other applications – or is this not possible any more by design?

PS: clicking the 'share by twitter' option does not work – but that's a different story I guess.

Comment: I tested and can't reproduce this (though I'm not trying to paste into Twitter, your issue sounds like the initial copy command is failing, so from that perspective it is working for me), but an easier workaround for sending to Twitter is selecting Copy on the bottom row of the share sheet (which copies the URL, though in a slightly different format), then pasting into Twitter.

Comment: Oh – thank you! I must admit I never saw that `copy` option. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it since it actualy answers my question…

Answer (score 1):

I tested and can't reproduce this (though I'm not trying to paste into Twitter, your issue sounds like the initial copy command is failing, so from that perspective it is working for me), but an easier workaround for sending to Twitter is selecting Copy on the bottom row of the share sheet (which copies the URL, though in a slightly different format), then pasting into Twitter.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this is a known problem for some on iOS 9 (Apple bug rdar://23129518). Somehow the paste does the previous copy rather than the current copy. The only workaround for the general copy problem seems to be just doing the copy twice.

More details in this article - http://www.imore.com/copy-and-paste-not-working-you-ios-9-heres-workaround